# Minimal set generators ideal submaximal minors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, determinants

Let $I$ an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X_1, \ldots X_n]$ and define the arithmetical rank of $I$ as:

$$ ark(I) = \textrm{min} \left\{m \in \mathbb{N},  \exists f_1, \ldots, f_m \in \mathbb{C}[X_1, \ldots X_n], \ \textrm{s.t.} \ \sqrt{I} = \sqrt{(f_1, \ldots, f_m)}\right\} $$

The arithmetical rank measures the least number of equations necessary to define the scheme associated to $I$ set-theoretically.

In the case $n=p^2$ and $I_{p-1}$ is the ideal of $(p-1)$-minors of the generic matrix:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} X_1 & X_2 & \ldots & X_{p} \\ X_{p+1} & X_{p+2} & \ldots & X_{2p} \\ \vdots & \vdots &\ldots & \vdots \\ X_{p^2-p+1} & X_{p^2-p+2} & \ldots & X_{p^2} \end{pmatrix}$$
the it is known that $ark(I_{p-1}) = 2p$.

The inequality $ark(I_{p-1})\leq 2p$ is not too difficult to prove and is a consequence, for instance, of the [Desnanot-Jacobi identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203102/geometric-interpretation-of-the-desnanot-jacobi-identity). The only proof I know of the inequality $ark(I_{p-1})\geq 2p$ is due to [Bruns and Schwänzl](https://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/wbruns/brunsw/pdf-article/NumbEqDet.published.pdf) (generalizing an idea of Newstead) and uses étale (or complex analytic) cohomology.

I am interested in a sligtly cruder invariant, namely, let me denote:

$$ ark_r(I) = \textrm{min} \left\{m \in \mathbb{N},  \exists f_1, \ldots, f_m \in \mathbb{C}[X_1, \ldots X_n]^{(\leq r)}, \ \textrm{s.t.} \ \sqrt{I} = \sqrt{(f_1, \ldots, f_m)}\right\} $$
where $\mathbb{C}[X_1, \ldots X_n]^{(\leq r)}$ is the vector space of polynomials of total degree less or equal to $r$. My question is the following:

**Question** : Is there an elementary proof (that is, not using etale or complex analytic cohomology; let's say, a proof I could teach to a good master student having a first course in Algebraic Geometry) that:
$$ ark_{p-1}(I_{p-1}) \geq 2p?$$

This inequality is an obvious consequence of the result of Bruns and Schwänzl I mentionned above. I am however hoping that adding the extra-condition that the $f_i$ should be of degree less or equal to the degree of a $p-1$-minor could make the inequality easier to prove via elementary representation theory/matrix theory/commutative algebra.